# Spring Kafka Consumer Threadpool

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-kafka

I am using Spring Kafka Consumer. I have set the concurrency to 10 and have 5 consumers created (for 5 topics). So there are 50 Spring Kafka Consumer threads.

What is the maximum number of threads I can have for Kafka Consumers? How can I increase the size of this thread pool? I have gone over the spring documentation but didn't find anything relavent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no limit; by default, each container uses a `SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor` for the threads; there is no pool involved.